# Call C++ functions from java program using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have an c++ code developed using `opencv` Library to extract bag of visual word . My code is based on the following methods :

`void extractTrainingVocabulary (const path& basepath)` ( path using boost library )

`void extractBOWDescriptor(const path& basepath, Mat& descriptors)`

Now , I need to call those methods from a java program using JNI

How should I write the Java native methods ? what's are its parametes ?

I try  :

`public native  void extractTrainingVocabulary ( String basepath)`

`public native void extractBOWDescriptor (String basepath , Mat descriptors)`

but when I run javah I got an error 'class not Mat found'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a C++ method (opencv) to java method (javacv )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562687/converting-a-c-method-opencv-to-java-method-javacv)

Comment: There is no `Mat` in Java. You're going to have to think about how to build an equivalent abstraction.

Comment: @AlanStokes yes there is no `Mat` in java , I can use it after adding opencv jars and tha associated native Library

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at [OpenCV's Java API](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html). You could use their types in a JNI wrapper for your library. Or, even rewrite your library in Java.